# pymongo "match" doesn't filter out the correct date

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I wrote a query that returns data that is within certain date (say 3/14 in this case), but the result returns something up to 3/29 (and nothing in 3/14)

my `match` is `{'$lte': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 14, 23, 59, 59, 999, tzinfo=tzutc()), '$gt': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 14, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzutc())}` which only gets data within the date, and my query command is

```
{'$match': match},
{'$unwind': '$'+needed_field},

{'$group': { 
     "_id":{
             "date":{
             "$concat": [
                 {"$substr": [{"$year": "$time"}, 0, 4 ]},
                                "-",
                               {"$substr": [{"$month": "$time"}, 0, 2 ]},
                                "-",
                               {"$substr": [{"$dayOfMonth": "$time"}, 0, 2 ]},
                            ]
                        },
                        "state":"$needed_field.state"
                    },
                "count":{"$sum": 1}}
   }]
```

(a little messy, sorry)

This query returns me something up to 3/29 for some reason. Am I not setting my match correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was querying a different $time field (there's another time within `needed_field`, which is the one being used by `$match`)